# Can others display my Amazon S3 public read only images in their website?(Making me pay for the usage)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have some images in Amazon S3, and I display them in my website, so public (not required to sign in)  can view the images.
I am not sure if anyone else also will be able to show the images in their website as they will have the urls of the images.If so how do I control?

(I do not want signed URL as i want every one to be able to view the images w/o signing in.)

Answer (score 3):

From [Restricting Access to a Specific HTTP Referrer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4):

> Suppose you have a website with domain name (`www.example.com` or `example.com`) with links to photos and videos stored in your S3 bucket, examplebucket. By default, all the S3 resources are private, so only the AWS account that created the resources can access them. To allow read access to these objects from your website, you can add a bucket policy that allows `s3:GetObject` permission with a condition, using the `aws:referer` key, that the get request must originate from specific webpages. The following policy specifies the `StringLike` condition with the `aws:Referer` condition key.

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Id":"http referer policy example",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":"s3:GetObject",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
      "Condition":{
        "StringLike":{"aws:Referer":["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The documentation also shows how to apply an explicit DENY.

Comment: I will check it out. sounds very promising. thank you John.